# Determine whether or not it's true that "$f(x,y) = -(x^2 - 1)^2 -(x^2y -x -1)^2$ has only two critical points, and they're local maximum points"

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

I believe this is not true because y is not independent from x on any of the first partial derivatives, therefore there are infinitely many critical points for x = 0. Is this correct?

Comment: To find the critical points, you need to solve a certain system, $2$ equations and $2$ unknowns. Not that difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking partial derivatives:
$$\begin{cases}f_x=-2(x^2-1)\cdot 2x-2(x^2y-x-1)(2xy-1)=0 \\ f_y=-2(x^2y-x-1)\cdot x^2=0\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} x_{1,2}=\pm 1 \\ y_{1,2}=2; 0\end{cases}.$$
The second derivative test:
$$f_{xx}(1,2)=-26<0, f_{yy}(1,2)=-2<0, \Delta=(-26)(-2)-(-6)^2>0 \Rightarrow \text{max},$$
$$f_{xx}(-1,0)=-10<0, f_{yy}(-1,0)=-2<0, \Delta=(-10)(-2)-2^2>0 \Rightarrow \text{max}.$$

Comment: This does not prove that x = 0 cannot be a solution to this system..

Comment: $x\ne 0$, because the first equation becomes $-2\ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$-(x^2-1)^2-(x^2y-x-1)^2\le 0$$ for all $x,y$ and this will be reached for $x=-1,y=0$